# Ubuntu 16.04 - Display driver/ screen resolution after installation

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, resolution, xrandr

A fresh install of Ubuntu was made on a quite old PC ( say - 10 years old ).
A 1920x 1080 monitor is connected via RGB... BUT showing a single possible screen res - 1280X1024 ( which is not my/ screens preferable one).

Since it is an old PC- I don't have any solid knowledge regarding it hardware ( MSI mother board, internal graphics card, E2140 1.60GHz, code 2 duo ... and that's about it ), so looking for any display drivers, was not a great success.

My main question is- What is the best way to start this search ?
1) using `xrandr` - showed only this 1 mode of resolution.
2) Is is a display driver issue ?
3) May be it is a Hardware issue ( since it is quite an old one...)

Anything else?

> Edit 1: *Perhaps* Motherboard is https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P4M900M2L/Specification

How can I get its drivers ? on manufacturer's site- it support windows only

> Edit 2: Motherboard model is P4M890
>
> Edit 3- Commandline output

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VIA Technologies, Inc. P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro] [1106:3343] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro] [1462:7255]
        Kernel modules: viafb
04:01.0 Audio device [0403]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller [1106:3288] (rev 10)


guy@desktop:~$ xrandr -d :0
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
guy@desktop:~$
```

Comment: Probably more a video (card) driver issue rather than actual monitor issue. If the video card's from a company (even internal has some company, nvidia/ati/others?) there should be a package in the repositories for video drivers. Search for ubuntu <video manufacturer> for instructions, askubuntu has a decent "meta question/answer" somewhere

Comment: where do you suggest to look for brand's name ? i didn't find any brand name onboard

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
lshw -c video
```

should give you some video info, the `product:` and `vendor:` lines being pertinent.

Then search for "ubuntu video " or "ubuntu video " to find out what others have done to solve the same problem.

A generic [ubuntu video driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+video+driver) shows some "meta" questions and promising sounding links like these, following the directions for your manufacturer should work:

- askubuntu's [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)
- How-to Geek's [How to Get the Latest NVIDIA, AMD, or Intel Graphics Drivers on Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/242045/how-to-get-the-latest-nvidia-amd-or-intel-graphics-drivers-on-ubuntu/)
- Ubuntu's community help wiki [VideoDriverHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VideoDriverHowto) (looks old, but the Ubuntu repo's packages are up to date anyway)

---

Your video appears to be VIA P4M890 and a web search for [ubuntu via p4m890 S3 UniChrome Pro](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+via+p4m890+S3+UniChrome+Pro) found a few promising leads, but it looks like some aren't supported anymore:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1055593 - sounds like *"The simple solution is to manually specificy the chipset in xorg.conf, disabling acceleration and adding some lines for resolutions."* but see the thread for specifics
- [I have this weird issue with my monitor. How can I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139051/i-have-this-weird-issue-with-my-monitor-how-can-i-fix-it)
  Not the exact same problem, but similar hardware? Highlights being:

  > On the same link provided above: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenChrome you can see that there is a compiling from source workaround that "probably" could work for the 3D part.
  >
  > There is also some workaround fixed to disable 3D altogether. By editing the `xorg.conf`: and adding the following:
  >
  > ```
  > Section "Module"
  >         Disable    "dri"
  > EndSection
  > ```

Comment: guy@desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c video [sudo] password for guy:   *-display UNCLAIMED        description: VGA compatible controller        product: P4M890 [S3 UniChrome Pro]        vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.        physical id: 0        bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0        version: 01        width: 32 bits        clock: 66MHz        capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list        configuration: latency=64 mingnt=2        resources: memory:a0000000-bfffffff memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: thank you very MUCH. So I was very close to the exact model of MSI's motherboard

Comment: using 2nd bullet in your answer - Should I use ubuntu's 17 drivers ?

Comment: That one must be pretty old, a web search for it and edited in a little more info. I didn't see Ubuntu 17 specifics in the How-To Geek page, but if it's using the default repositories they should be up-to-date for your ubuntu (16), and even adding a PPA often automatically picks the right ubuntu

Comment: Added Edit 3 in my question